# What "requirement" do I need to give to pip?

Tags: python

I am trying to install [PyECC](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyECC/) on a Windows 7 machine. Pip is pretty inconsistent, so I'm not sure what it wants this time. First I ran `pip install PyECC` and got

```
Collecting PyECC
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement PyECC
  Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable
(use --allow-external PyECC to allow).
  No distributions at all found for PyECC
```

So I ran `pip install --allow-external PyECC` and got

```
You must give at least one requirement to install (see "pip help install")
```

What requirement? The help command was no help at all and the Pypi page doesn't give pip instructions.

Comment: try this: `pip install --allow-all-external --allow-unverified elementtree elementtree`

Answer (score 7):

Using `pip install --allow-external PyECC`, you are allowing pip to download PyECC from an external repository should it need to but you aren't telling it what to install.

You need to use `pip install --allow-external PyECC PyECC` to tell it to install PyECC while allowing it to download PyECC from an external source.

Comment: Error : Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement PyECC. Could you possibly give another way to install PyECC

Answer (score 1):

With version pip 7.1.2:

The probably I found was the command is actually `--allow-all-external`

`--allow-external`, while being what it SAYS to use, doesn't seem to exist.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As the PyECC is no longer available. You can use Py-seccure for Simple Elliptic Curve Cryptography in Python.

Steps for installation is here : [py-seccure](https://github.com/bwesterb/py-seccure)

Hope it helps for anyone searching for Elliptic Curve Cryptography implementation in python.